# If variable is equal to any value in a list

Tags: python, list

I want to make a IF statement inside a for loop, that I want it to be triggered if the variable is equal to any value in the list.

Sample data:

```
list = [variable1, variable2, variable3]
```

Right now I have this sample code:

```
for k, v in result_dict.items():
   if k == 'varible1' or k == 'variable2' or k == 'variable2':
```

But the problem is the list will grow larger and I don't to have to create multiple OR statements for every variable.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the `in` operator is for.  Do:

```
list = [variable1, variable2, variable3]
for k, v in result_dict.items():
   if k in list:
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is with sets:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 'three', 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
>>> keys = set(l).intersection(d.keys())
>>> keys
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

Then you can iterate over those keys:

```
for k in set(l).intersection(d.keys()):
    do_something(d[k])
```

This should be more efficient than repetitively calling `in` on the list. Call `set()` on the shortest of the list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You may need another FOR loop.

```
for k, v in result_dict.items():
   for i in list: 
      if i==k:
```